# Deleting Push Channel After Sending A Push with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send a push notification out across a channel indicating that the channel is about to be closed, so I need to send the notification out across the channel, then remove that channel from the PFInstallation attribute "channels". However, when I do this I get an exception saying: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'

Here is the code where I call this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        ChatSession *session = self.chatSessions[indexPath.row];
        [self.chatSessions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        NSString *pushChannel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"channel_%@", session.sessionName];
        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        [push setChannel:pushChannel];
        [push setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has ended your chat.", session.myAlias]];
        [push sendPushInBackground];

        [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] removeObject:pushChannel forKey:@"channels"];
        [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];

        [session removeChatSession];

    }
}
```

How can I do this without getting this message? It doesn't even really make sense to me in the first place why I would be getting this message. Why should a PFInstallation need to be subscribed to a channel to send a push out across it? Then a user would get his/her own push notifications.

I would post the stack trace... but it's really just a long list of hexadecimal addresses, which wouldn't make any sense without examining my code compiled into assembly.

Anyways, please help me figure out how send the last push message then drop the channel. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception stack trace. If it's parse related then take it to their forum / bug tracking system

Comment: Stack trace is just a bunch of hexadecimal addresses